# CouchDB 2.0 View Compaction

Tags: couchdb, cloudant

I've been playing around with the CouchDB 2.0 Developer Preview, and loaded up a database with ~200M records.  I noticed that each of the nodes properly handles automatic database compaction, but it appears only some of the views are being automatically compacted.  With a dataset this size, we need to reduce the footprint as much as possible.

Using the old Couchdb view compaction API, I am able to kick off view compaction using the backend port on each node in the cluster, but only on the shard databases that have the actual design doc.  Do I need to manually add the design documents to each of the shard databases?

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible to do this without adding design documents to each shard so this looks like a bug in the 2.0 developer preview. The CouchDB compaction daemon is affected by the same issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/COUCHDB-2817